# Tableview item dependencies javafx

Tags: javafx, dependencies, tableview

Good evening,

I am working on a project and I'm at lost at how to configure my tableviews to depend on each other.  I would like for the parts in one tableview to depend on the products in the other.  How would I go about doing that? I prefer to not use sql at the moment just to keep everything simple as possible.  The code snippet is listed below:

```
public class maincontroller {

private  ObservableList<Part> parts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

 private ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

//code to swap between controllers

  @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        partsID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("partID"));
        partsName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        partsinvlevel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("instock"));
        partscost.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        parttable.setItems(parts);

        productsID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("productID"));

        productsName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        productsInvlevel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("instock"));
        productsprice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        producttable.setItems(products);


        parttable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Part> observable, Part oldValue, Part newValue) -> {


        });


        producttable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Product> observable, Product oldValue, Product newValue) -> {

        });


    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure about the relationship between `Part` and `Product`. From the context, I would assume each specific `Product` would have its own list of `Part`s that is related to it. I would also assume that that list of `Part`s is stored within `Product`.

Product:

```
public class Product
{
    private final ObservableList<Part> parts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public final ObservableList<Part> getParts() { return parts; }
    ........
}
```

This is what you can do:

```
producttable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(observable, oldProduct, newProduct) ->
{
    if (newProduct != null)
    {
        parts.clear();
        parts.addAll(newProduct.getParts());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was bugging me because I didn't know the right approach to use to have the parts and products to depend on each other, i.e. the user will put in information on part A and then the user will enter the product information into the other table.  Then if the user deletes part A, the product information will be deleted as well.  Again thanks for you assistance!